# Google Analytics Async Code

Tags: google-analytics, asynchronous

I am using new async code of Google Analytics, would it be correct to call GA.js twice in the same page, if not, is there a way to do that ?

My  problem is I need to account two PageViews on a booking form using flash, the trouble is that user may not necessarilly get to the second stage but close the window n the first stage.

```
  <!-- Step one, I need to record a pageview -->

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-6173481-3']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/Step1']);
  (function() {
   var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
   ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') +    '.google-analytics.com/ga.js'; 
   var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
   })();

  <!-- Step two of the process i define a function that will get called by flash and record another pageview-->

   function completed (){

   var _gaq = _gaq || [];
   _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-6173481-3']);
   _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/Step2']);
  (function() {
   var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
  ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') +    '.google-analytics.com/ga.js'; 
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
  <!-- Step one, I need to record a pageview -->
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-6173481-3']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/Step1']);
  (function() {
   var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
   ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') +    '.google-analytics.com/ga.js'; 
   var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
   })();

  <!-- Step two of the process i define a function that will get called by flash and record another pageview-->
   function completed (){
   _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/Step2']);    
  }
```

Then call `completed()` from flash when desired.